# Como adicionar um view dinamicamente ao android conforme registro no mysql

Tags: android, mysql, view, volley

Gostaria de saber como faço para adicionar um view (RelativeLayout) dinamicamente no meu xml, conforme forem sendo encontrados registros no meu BD Mysql... (Minha conexão é feita através da lib Volley)

Comment: mahenrocha, qual a sua dúvida especificamente ? Você já recebe os dados e quer saber como popular ?

Comment: Entao... eu consigo puxar os dados do mysql atraves da lib volley só q eu quero q a cada registro recebido ele carregue um relative layout de tamanho pequeno dentro de um scrollview para mostrar uma foto e uma legenda embaixo. Como se fosse uma galeria de imagens com legendas dos registros do banco. Deu para entender?

Comment: É possível sim e não é difícil, porém, por experiência própria, não é uma boa ideia adicionar vários Relatives Layout direto no container, cada View vai alocar logo de inicio o que precisará de memória, então você vai se ver facilmente com erros de memória. O jeito correto seria criar um `ListView` ou `RecyclerView` contendo um Relative e dentro deste relative ter a imagem e o TextView para a legenda. Desta forma, só carregará o que está visível + 2.

Comment: Será que vc consegueria me mostrar algum link q ensine isso? ou então se puder postar alguma solução simples para mim saber qual a melhor maneira de tratar isso?

Comment: Postei um exemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para implementar a lista você precisará de basicamente 4 partes:

1. O layout que possuirá a lista
2. O layout que de cada item da lista
3. Um adaptador personalizado
4. Atribuir esse adaptador à sua lista, passando uma lista com os dados que você trouxe do Volley

1-) Layout que possuirá a lista: **main_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_verde">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/minha_lista">
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Sem segredo aqui, só um Frame com uma ListView dentro, é importante atribuir um ID à ela

2-)Layout de cada Item: **list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:id="@+id/minhaImagem"
/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/minhaLegenda"
android:layout_below="@id/minhaImagem"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Aqui não me preocupei com a estética, depois você deve formatar da maneira que desejar. Esse layout será repetido para cada item.

3-) Adaptador Personalizado: **myAdapter.java**

```
public class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SeuObjeto> {

    public Context context;
    public List<SeuObjeto> lista;

    public myAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<SeuObjeto> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        this.context = context;
        this.lista= objects;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// Primeiro checa se a view ainda não foi inflada, se não infla
        if (convertView == null) {
// Inflando a nova View
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
// Now we can fill the layout with the right values
        TextView txtLegenda= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minhaLegenda);

       ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minhaImagem);

        SeuObjeto seuObjeto = lista.get(position);

        txtLegenda.setText(seuObjeto.getLegenda());

        img.setImageBitmap(seuObjeto.getImagem()); // <------- Aqui você deve verificar como você está recebendo a imagem, e como vai atribuí-la à ImageView



        return convertView;
    }



}
```

Aqui estendemos um ArrayAdapter, ele recebe um objeto, se seus dados não são construídos em um objeto, eu recomendo, é mais tranquilo pra tratar.

4-) Atribuição do Adapter à ListView: **MinhaActivity.java**

Dentro do seu onCreate

```
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.minha_lista);
        List<SeuObjeto> minhaLista = meusDados; // <---------- Aqui não sei como você recebe os dados, se usa o Volley com Gson, provavelmente você facilmente terá essa lista com os objetos.
        myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter (this,R.layout.list_item,minhaLista);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Aqui não tem muito segredo também, depois de receber os dados através do Volley, organize eles em uma lista de objetos, um objeto com a imagem e a legenda, depois construa seu adaptador passando (Contexto, layout dos itens, Dados), atribua esse adapter à lista e tudo pronto

Comment: maravilha... só mais uma pergunta... para trabalhar com grids e colocar imagens? o que preciso modificar?

Comment: @mahenrocha dentro daquele layout `list_item` você pode trabalhar como quiser, pode trocar o RelativeLayout por Grid, Table ou qualquer outra coisa, ele será repetido em cada item do adapter. Para colocar a imagem precisa saber como você recebe ela do webservice, mas é só atribuir à ImageView de acordo com o método que você está salvando no Objeto